# Applying the definition of adjoint operator

Tags: adjoint-operators

How do I apply the definition of adjoint operator in this problem?
U and V are two arbitrary operators, not necessarily Hermitian. Show that
(UV )† = V †U†.

Comment: You should be more sincere next time while asking questions,it is not at all for very easy problems that you can answer by little thinking.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
 $$\langle (UV)^Tx, \, y\rangle = \langle x,\, UVy\rangle =\langle U^Tx, \, Vy\rangle =\langle V^T(U^Tx), \, y\rangle$$
Substituting the standard basis vectors $e_i$ and $e_j$ for $x$ and $y$ yields that the $i,j$ entries of $(UV)^T$ and $V^TU^T$ are the same.

Comment: thank you so much. i have confirmed my answer. I used (u,v) instead of (x,y).